# Positivity of a rational function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions

A rational function is called positive if all its Taylor coefficients are positive.
  Friedrichs-Lewy conjecture states the positivity of the rational function
 \begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{
(1-x)(1- y)+(1- y)(1-z)+(1-z)(1-x)}
= \sum\limits_{ k,m,n\ge0}
a_{k,m, n }x^k y^mz^n.  \end{eqnarray*}
The conjecture was first proved by G. Szego.

Let $P_n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1-x_i)$, is it true that the following rational function is positive \begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{P_n}{1-x_i}}=\sum\limits_{i_1,i_2\cdots, i_n\ge 0}a_{i_1,i_2\cdots, i_n }x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\cdots x_n^{i_n}\quad? \end{eqnarray*}

A reference:

> Armin Straub, *Positivity of Szegö's rational function*, Advances in Applied Mathematics
>   **41** Issue 2 (2008) pp 255–264, doi:[10.1016/j.aam.2007.10.001](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2007.10.001), ([Wayback Machine pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20170922235432/http://129.81.170.14/~tamdeberhan/positivity.pdf))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is yes.

This was already proved in Gabor Szegö's [original paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/tgmq242t51414177/) from 1933:

G. Szegö, *Über gewisse Potenzreihen mit lauter positiven Koeffizienten*, Mathematische Zeitschrift, Volume 37, Number 1, 674-688, DOI: 10.1007/BF01474608

The result can be found in Paragraph 3 "Verallgemeinerungen". However, apparently the simplified proof method due to Armin Straub which you mention applies also to this generalization.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken; the new link is https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01474608.